# VS Code Will Not Save Changes - Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, admin, file-permissions

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the advised solutions have worked for me. I am on a Mac and trying to save changes to a VS Code file. When I press save, it says

> Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.

When I choose to "Retry as Sudo" I enter my password and it says

> Failed to save... Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted

I have tried a couple of different things to open VS Code with admin privileges, including running it from the terminal with the command:

> sudo open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron

and manually adding VS Code to my path using the commands

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

I have yet to find anything that affects the failed to save error, and if anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Its no longer an issue after running:

`$ sudo chown -R username .`

Hope this will resolve all kind of permission issues.

Comment: This works just good, an even easier way is to just run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) .`

Answer (score 9):

**05-03-2021**

This works for me.

`Sudo chown –R username folder-path`

**e.g**

`sudo chown -R sampath /Users/sampath/Desktop/Test/renoTracker/platforms/ios`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my issue by adding user here in permission. May be this can solve your issue
[image]